# WHy does user log out after the session id is regenrated?

Tags: authentication, security, session

I want to have a secure session variable for logged in users, where the session id keeps changing every 30 mins and so. the problem is I want the session ID to change but every 30 mins, the user gets logged out as if there is nothing else.

All i want is a secure session for logged in users. before this i only set the session variable (i.e $_SESSION['user'] = $username) when the user logged in.

but now i tried this code:

```
<?php 

ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);

session_set_cookie_params([
  'lifetime' => 1800,
  'domain' => 'localhost',
  'path' => '/',
  'secure'=> true,
  'httponly'=> true

]);
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['last_regeneration'])){
        regenerate_session_id_logged();
    } else {
        $interval = 60 * 30;
        if(time() - $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] >= $interval){
            regenerate_session_id_logged();
        }
    }
}else{

    if(!isset($_SESSION['last_regeneration'])){
        regenerate_session_id();
    } else {
        $interval = 60 * 30;
        if(time() - $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] >= $interval){
            regenerate_session_id();
        }
    }
}



function regenerate_session_id(){
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] = time();
}
function regenerate_session_id_logged(){
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $userid =$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $newSessionId = session_create_id();
    $sessionId = $newSessionId . "_" . $userid;
    session_id($sessionId);
    $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] = time();
   
}
```

and on my header page which is connected to all the other pages i check if the user is logged in.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//the rest of the code
}
```

But still every 30 mins the user gets logged out. Am I missing something? or is there a better way or should I just use a session variable like before?